# Arquillian JAVA EE 5 and JBoss 4.2

Tags: java, testing, jboss

I now it's a pretty peculiar, uninteresting and old combination of application server and JVM version but that is what's being used in my company nowadays. I would need to be able to test EJB3 components with JTA(TransactionManagementType.BEAN) and access to database through JPA 1.0/Hibernate

I've been struggling with this one and a half day by now, with very little luck so far. I found some answers here in Stackoverflow and in JBoss Community forums but all of them involve using Java 6. I've already got tests of this kind running using OpenEJB (written without Arquillian) but -hopefully- this year we will be migrating to a new application server and it would very useful to have the same set of tests in Arquillian to be able to check that EJBs that are working now on JBoss 4.2 will work too in another newer application server (likely to be JBoss 7)

Would anyone know a working Arquillian example with these requirements?

Comment: There are some testcases related to JBoss AS 4.2 in the Arquillian Container Adapter. Not exactly the same as your question, but it might give you hint; https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-jbossas/tree/master/jbossas-managed-4.2/src/test/java/org/jboss/arquillian/container/jbossas/managed_4_2

Comment: Thank you for the help.I been working with those examples for a while having some success but not with my required EJB3/JPA/JTA/JDK5/JBoss 4.2 combination. I know too your post https://community.jboss.org/thread/196745?_sscc=t. I'll keep working on it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after fighting a little bit more with this, I put together a solution combining Arquillian, JAVA 5, JBoss4.2 y JPA. Anyone interested can found it [in this GitHub miniproject](https://github.com/pvm30/arquillian-jbossas-4.2)

Regards